# Problem with negative "multido" and "fp"

Tags: fp, multido

Is there a way to use "negative" numbers with `multido` and `fp`?
In the code below, it works with `\Nx=4+0.5` but not with `\Nx=4+-0.5`.

Additional question: is there a way to do this without using package `fp`? I think it is possible with calculating in PostScript but I don't know how to do this.

Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,5)(-5,5)
\multido{\Nx=4+-0.5}{12}{
  \FPeval{\moncalcul}{\Nx^2/4+1} 
  \psdots(\Nx,\moncalcul)
  }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The raising of a negative number to a power seems to be the problem. Using `abs` around `\Nx` for the square works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,5)(-5,5)
\multido{\Nx=4+-0.5}{12}{
  \FPeval{\moncalcul}{abs(\Nx)^2/4+1}
  \psdots(\Nx,\moncalcul)
  }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Other working variants without `abs`

- Function **`pow`** instead of infix operator `^`:

  ```
  \FPeval{\moncalcul}{pow(\Nx, 2)/4+1}
  ```
- Using a **multiplication**:

  ```
  \FPeval{\moncalcul}{(\Nx*\Nx)/4 + 1}
  ```
- [**Reverse Polish notation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation):

  ```
  \FPupn\moncalcul{\Nx{} 2 pow 4 div 1 add}
  ```

## Calculation in PostScript without package `fp`

```
\psdots(! \Nx\space dup 2 exp 4 div 1 add)
```

or simple multiplication:

```
\psdots(! \Nx\space dup dup mul 4 div 1 add)
```

There must be *two* values on the stack for the *x* and *y* coordinates.
Since TeX skips spaces after command names, `\space` inserts the needed space to separate the number from the following operator. The name for the `pow` function is `exp` in PostScript.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
  \begin{pspicture}(-5,5)(-5,5)
    \multido{\Nx=4+-0.5}{12}{
      \psdots(! \Nx\space dup 2 exp 4 div 1 add)
    }
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your very complete answer.
So with RPN I tried this directly : `\psdots(! \Nx \Nx 2 pow 4 div 1 add)`
But it doesn't work. Is there a solution like this with no use of fp ?

Comment: @Oli See updated answer.